# C++, Python or PHP, infinitive loop

Tags: php, python, c++, mysql

So I need create some execution loop to do some stuff using mysql and xml (parse it).

For this i was need do it using PHP, but as everybody (php devs) know php has time limit for script execution. So php is out.

Next one is C++, I wanted to do it but it's not simple as I thought in first time.

And last one is python, I think it's the best way to do it, but I don't have deep knowledge in it.

So base question is - can python do infinitive loop? Has it 'script execution limit' or I can like C++ create while with while(true) and it will never ends ?

ADDED: Question was resolved because was found solution not to use python (that is was the main question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

99.9999% of the time, an infinite loop isn't required for data processing. I'd probably use a cron script for that, and C++ is just total and utter overkill. However, if you want an infinite loop in a PHP script:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);//no max exec time
while(true)
{
    echo 'Still running',PHP_EOL;
}
```

See the manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)
After that, depending on how big the datasets are you are processing, you may hit the memory limit (I think the default RAM PHP uses is set to 128M). This can be solved, too, by either changing the php.ini file's `memory_limit` setting to 256M, or more... or by setting it to -1 to do away with the memory limit all together. See [the man pages here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
while(true)
{
    //do stuff
    if ($foobar === 'whatever') break;//exit script
}
```

Again, if the script is a CLI script, the max execution time should be infinite already (by default, PHP CLI mode has no max exec time). If your script looks something like this:

```
<?php
require(realpath(__DIR__.'/lib/Xml.php');//include some script
```

The `require`'d file doesn't need to call `set_time_limit` again, because you're just *requiring* it. Think of the `require` line as a C-style header: the preprocessor just gets the contents of that file, and pastes it into the source file containing the `#include` directive

---

If you want, however, a process to be active *all* the time, and kick into action every once in a while: take a look at *node.js*. Compared to PHP or Python, node has 1 undeniable benefit: it's *great* at sitting idle. Instead of a `while(true){}` loop, using events (which probably translate to interupts at some low level) there's a good chance you'll significantly reduce load on your system

Comment: this changes roles only on executed file of on all php files that will exe on server? I mean will they change php.ini or just change them on for current php file?

Comment: @user1954544: If you include the call in a single script, than the timelimit for that script is infinite. If you alter the php.ini settings, then all scripts will have no time limits. If your script `require`'s another script, then you needn't call `set_time_limit` a second time, because the code in that script is getting executed by the first script. The second script doesn't start a second process...

Comment: so this changes will role on scriptes that are called, I think I got it, thanks, it helps a lot

Comment: You really shouldn't use PHP for something its not designed for

Comment: @JakobBowyer: PHP was never _designed_ as such... it wasn't designed to be a language initially, but now it is one. Besides: doing some simple mysql/xml data processing is something PHP is perfectly capable of doing... I don't think I really get your comment in this case

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I disagree, it is still a shoddy, bad and horrible templating "langauge" wrapping over the top of some old C hacks. The original inventer even admitted he isn't any good at language design.

Comment: @JakobBowyer: The original _inventor_ said he never attempted to create a language... PHP just took off by accident, and was picked up by 2 Israeli students who developed the first Zend engine. I never said it was well designed (I've often called PHP _"dessign"_ the principle of design by afterthought), but like it or not: PHP is a programming language. COBOL is, too, that doesn't make it a good one. I'm just asking to back up your claim that this is a bad use-case for PHP: DB connections + DOM parsing are things PHP doesn't handle too bad.

Comment: Besides: PHP has come a long way since PHP3... and, IMO, there is a case to be made for saying it's no longer _just a templating language_, but has grown to a (yes, again, I admit messy) programming language: byte-code compilation, OO support, advanced caching, GTK API and even (though that's where I say PHP shouldn't be used) threading support...

Comment: Even still, there are still too many arguments that preclude php from being considered a half decent language. This task would be far better done in a language that at least performs well, has clean syntax, doesn't require dirty ini hacks to increase runtime duration, and has a decent runtime that doesn't have so many horrible corner cases that developing any sizeable application or program will seriously hurt a programmers sanity.

Comment: @JakobBowyer: perhaps this may explain my _"fanatic"_ defending of PHP. I far prefer the design of C over PHP, but I don't see it as fair to dismiss a language that _does_ have some good qualities too it (I'm writing a blog post on the matter) as being _just a templaling "language"_. That's what I had to respond to here. So could we just agree on what wikipedia says _"Programming languages such as Perl, Python, PHP, Ruby, C#, and Java support template processing either natively, or through add-on libraries and modules. "_?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45178/discussion-between-jakob-bowyer-and-elias-van-ootegem)

Answer (score 0):

I guess every language can do something like this

```
$looping = true;

while ($looping) {

    //magic here

    if ($condition == true) {
        $looping = false;
    }
}
```

But if you parse something, I'd prefer kinda foreach $line/$word/$character or whatever.

Comment: Or use the `break` statement if the language has one.

Comment: Yes, but not every language have execution limit. ;)

Comment: @user1954544: check my comment + answer: PHP has no exec limit if the script is running from the command line, _and_ you can set the max exec time to infinity with a single, simple function call